# React-Native Google-SignIn log out not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-signin

I have a problem. When I login on my app and I refresh, then I go and try to log out, I have to manually refresh to see that I am logged out. Basically what happens is, it gets stuck inside my try catch statement, hence I can't see anything but if I refresh i'm logged out all good.
However, if i remove the `await` keyword from `GoogleSignIn.revokeAcess()` and `GoogleSignin.signOut()` it works as expected. The docs show an example and they're using await. Is it bad practice for me to remove the await? Thanks in advance.

code:

```
export function logout(): ThunkResult<void> {
  return function(dispatch) {
    Keychain.resetGenericPassword().then(async () => {
      amplitude.logEvent('Log out');
      LoginManager.logOut();
      try {
        const isSignedIn = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
        if (isSignedIn) {
          console.log('gets here'); // LOGS THIS
          await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess(); // GETS STUCK HERE
          console.log('passed revoke access'); // doesn't log this
          await GoogleSignin.signOut();
          console.log('passed signOut');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        amplitude.logEvent('Failed Google Logout', err);
      }
      console.log('passes');
      resetAllPreferences();
      dispatch(postLogout());
      dispatch(fetchMoreActivities());
    });
  };
}
```

and then

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: AsyncDispatch) => ({
  synchronizeReads: () => dispatch(synchronizeReadInsights()),
  logout: () => dispatch(logout()), // here i take the action above from my actions file
});
```

and use it like

```
const onLogoutPress = async () => {
  await synchronizeReads();
  logout();
  Navigation.pop(componentId);
};
```

Comment: where are the GoogleSignIn  function definitions ?

Comment: In the `import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';` yarn package?